# Could ZFS fix silent corruption on a single drive with two mirrored partitions?

Tags: raid, storage, zfs, filesystem-corruption

ZFS can detect silent data corruption (or "bitrot"); with a proper mirroring or `raidz` setup it may also repair such corruption.  Thus, would it be possible to split a disk into two (or more) partitions, create a mirror `vdev` from the two, and then repair any corruption using the other partition's duplicate?  If so, are there any extra considerations or problems to be considered?  (One issue is that this setup would offer no protection against actual hardware failure, a common need for RAID setups.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *technically*. However there is absolutely no reason to do this. ZFS has already solved this problem more efficiently with the dataset property called `copies`. Setting `copies=2` will cause ZFS to make an additional hardware-level copy of all file data that gets written, which will then be used specifically to protect from bit rot. (Note this is not retroactive: if the property is not set at the dataset's creation, it will only apply to data that is written *after* the property is set).

Comment: I have accepted this answer since it is more useful to me.  I was wondering though: do the same caveats apply about drive wear which user10489 mentioned in their answer?

Comment: Sure. All SSDs have a limited amount of write operations they can do before the chance of failure becomes high. You can find this in the product specs. `copies=2` will naturally double the writes and get you to the drive's write limit twice as fast. I wouldn't worry about it, however. Fear about write limits were instilled in people 10 years ago when it was easy to hit those limits. Not so today with drives having write limits in the hundreds of terabytes.

Comment: Server grade SSDs have a DWPD rating you can use to estimate lifetime based on your write rate (and use that even before you buy them).  I would assume `copies=2` would have better performance than two mirrors on the same disk.

Answer (score 0):

ZFS checksums every block, so it can detect silent corruption without a mirror.  But the mirror would let it correct it, assuming that zfs doesn't fail both partitions at the same time.

Putting the two mirror halves on the same disk seems to me like a terrible idea for many reasons.

It'll halve your performance or worse, probably much worse because it will force your disk to thrash on every block read and write. It will increase drive wear by an order of magnitude. It doesn't increase reliability. Both partitions are likely to go offline at once if the disk gets errors. It'll halve your available space with no benefit. And that's assuming zfs doesn't smartly reject that config outright. Normally mirroring increases read performance -- this won't.

Comment: Could you explain your reasons why it would be a terrible idea to put the two mirror halves on the same disk?